# Выделяется ли «определённо» запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, прописная-строчная, наречия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые для обособления слова "определённо" в следующем предложении?
*Подрастающее поколение, **определённо,** пришло в Мир с миссией восстановить нашу Землю и все ценности!*

Благодарю Вас!

Answer (score 2):

• [*Определенно*](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/480/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE) может быть наречием, вводным словом или частицей (в ответной реплике).

• [ОПРЕДЕЛЕННО](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_509), *вводное слово* (в начале предложения или части сложного предложения)

То же, что «конечно, несомненно». Интонационно отделяется от последующих слов.
***Определенно,** я отношусь к человечеству лучше, чем оно ко мне.* В. Токарева, Рубль шестьдесят – не деньги. ***Определенно,** он стал похож повадками на маститого театрального актера.* З. Прилепин, Санькя.
При отсутствии интонационного выделения, а также при употреблении не в начале предложения (или части сложного предложения) слово «определенно» не является вводным и не обособляется.
*И яркая, броская внешность ее **определенно** была мне знакома.* А. и Г. Вайнеры, Лекарство против страха.

• Я бы оформила ваше предложение таким образом:
*Подрастающее поколение **определённо** пришло в Мир с миссией **—** восстановить нашу Землю и все ценности!*

*Первый замглавы президентской администрации на должностной лестнице **определенно** стоит выше патриарха РПЦ, не говоря уже об иерархах остальных конфессий* (Сергей Шелин. Всемирная прохиндиада).
*Вот тут московский мальчик с двумя курсами ИФЛИ **определенно** угодил пальцем в небо* (А. А. Бушков. Дверь в чужую осень (сборник)).

**P. S.** У вас какое-то особенное, возвышенное значение имеют слова "**М**ир" и "**З**емля"?
При обычном употреблении они пишутся со строчной (маленькой) буквы.

> [§ 178. Астрономические названия](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=85#pp85)
> **Примечание.** Слова *солнце, земля, луна* не как астрономические названия пишутся со строчной буквы: *закат солнца, обработка земли, свет луны* (ср.: *полёт на Луну, протуберанцы на Солнце, происхождение Земли*).
>
> [§ 203. Прописные буквы в особом стилистическом употреблении](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=93#pp93)
> С прописной буквы могут писаться некоторые нарицательные существительные в контекстах, где им приписывается особый высокий смысл: *Родина, Отечество, Отчизна, Свобода, Добро, Честь, Человек, Учитель, Мастер* и т. п.